# Database for live mobile tracking

Tags: sql, mongodb

I'm developing an app that allows to track a mobile device instantly (live) ... I need an of advice. The application must send the location to a webservice that in it's turn records the received data in a database.

What would be, in your opinion, the best way to store the location values?

I'm new in using bigdata and I'm afraid that simple sql requests wont be able to do the work properly ... I imagine if there is lot of users and each user send a request each 1sec I'll have issue with the database ...

An advice ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you could have a look into the geospatial queries in mongo, if you chose to go ahead with mongodb.
[Refer here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) 
[And here](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/storing-and-querying-location-data-mongodb)

for the design of the database would depend on the nature of the query (essentially the read and write).

[Worth having a look into](https://www.firebase.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Working at [Cintric](https://cintric.com/) we landed on using elasticsearch. We process billions of location points in real time and provide advanced analytics to our users.

We started with mongoDB and ran into a lot of troubles, eventually leading to a painful migration.

Our stack currently has mobile devices dump location updates into AWS Kinesis, which are then processed by AWS Lambda handlers, and then dumped into elasticsearch. We're able to serve, process and store 300 million requests/month for only a few hundred dollars/month. Analytics for our dashboard add additional cost but for your needs I would highly recommend checking out your options on AWS.